# Google Drive Api how to get data of directory with subdirectories if provided share url?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, drive

I'm using google drive api V3 and i'm able to get files data of a directory by id like below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="DirID"+in+parents
Method : "GET"
Authorization : Bearer "access_token"
```

But i want to get data from directory by its share url. Like any google drive user if share directory with permission to my email id then how can i get data from api?

Is there any other way to get data from directory share url ?

Please help!!
Thanks!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, when the folder of other user is shared with your Google account and the folder is not publicly shared, you can access to it using your access token.

Comment: @Tanaike, yes you are right i'm able to get data of shared drive but i want to get data from public url without share. When i try to get data with public url directory id then i'm facing issue of wrong credentials. Do we need token to get data for public url dir data ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Tanaike, Public url also need access token, its working with token. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, there is a folder which was publicly shared. You want to retrieve the data from the URL of the publicly shared folder. Is my understanding correct? After I could correctly understand your situation, I would like to think of the solution and workaround.

Comment: @Tanaike, i got data from public url by parsing id from share url but i dont know why api gave response when i try without token. Response : "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
Why public url need authentication ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. So can you explain about the detail information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197756/discussion-between-sourabh-bhutani-and-tanaike).